# dotnet add project wrong configuration

Tags: .net, command-line-interface

some time ago I evaluated the usage of the .NET Core-CLI. Which is really simple and easy to use. I used it to add several projects to a existing solution file. After building my solution on the build server i had a strange behavior. Even for release configuration the debug configuration was build. After some investigation I found out the useage of the .NET Core-CLI caused the issue.

I reproduced it with an empty solution where I just wanted to add one project.

Empty solution:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.31205.134
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {BD04E6CD-1AA7-4995-8A25-E0559BC2E184}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

After adding the project manual with Visual Studio:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.31205.134
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "ClassLibrary1", "ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj", "{8492F4EC-BE0F-439A-B28F-E5DB871C9F95}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {8492F4EC-BE0F-439A-B28F-E5DB871C9F95}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {8492F4EC-BE0F-439A-B28F-E5DB871C9F95}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {8492F4EC-BE0F-439A-B28F-E5DB871C9F95}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {8492F4EC-BE0F-439A-B28F-E5DB871C9F95}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {BD04E6CD-1AA7-4995-8A25-E0559BC2E184}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Everything looks fine a configuration for Debug and Release is added.

If i try the same with the .NET Core-CLI:

```
dotnet sln ClassLibrary1.sln add ClassLibrary1/ClassLibrary1.csproj
```

The result is a little bit different from my expected result:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.31205.134
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "ClassLibrary1", "ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj", "{8492F4EC-BE0F-439A-B28F-E5DB871C9F95}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {BD04E6CD-1AA7-4995-8A25-E0559BC2E184}
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Debug|x64 = Debug|x64
        Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        Release|x64 = Release|x64
        Release|x86 = Release|x86
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {8492F4EC-BE0F-439A-B28F-E5DB871C9F95}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {8492F4EC-BE0F-439A-B28F-E5DB871C9F95}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {8492F4EC-BE0F-439A-B28F-E5DB871C9F95}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {8492F4EC-BE0F-439A-B28F-E5DB871C9F95}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {8492F4EC-BE0F-439A-B28F-E5DB871C9F95}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {8492F4EC-BE0F-439A-B28F-E5DB871C9F95}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {8492F4EC-BE0F-439A-B28F-E5DB871C9F95}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {8492F4EC-BE0F-439A-B28F-E5DB871C9F95}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {8492F4EC-BE0F-439A-B28F-E5DB871C9F95}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {8492F4EC-BE0F-439A-B28F-E5DB871C9F95}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {8492F4EC-BE0F-439A-B28F-E5DB871C9F95}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {8492F4EC-BE0F-439A-B28F-E5DB871C9F95}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

The project was succesfully added but all configurations point to Debug. That is the explaination why also in Release configuration Debug is build.

Has anybody a explanation for this behavior or am I doing something wrong?

The .Net Core version is 3.1.408.15681

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has approved the problem.
See:
https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/dotnet-add-project-wrong-configuration/1410504?from=email&space=61&entry=problem